# Upgrading 12.04 to 14.04 beta directly (without the intermediate 12.10 release)

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, beta

I was trying to upgrade from 12.04 LT to 14.04 beta using update manager and using this command.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade --check-dist-upgrade-only --devel-release
```

But it is showing

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
New release '12.10' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it
```

How can I skip the other versions and upgrade directly to 14.04 beta ?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't done it yet myself. You have backed up all your data, right?

Comment: yeah. But wats the need for commenting if you don't know  :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like it checks for the next release, instead of the next lts release. You may need to edit `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and set `Prompt=lts`.

To open the file for editing, run `sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`, after editing, pess `ctrl-o` to save, `ctrl-x` to exit.

Also make sure you have `update-manager-core` installed with 
`sudo apt-get install update-manager-core`

[info source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PreciseUpgrades#Network_Upgrade_for_Ubuntu_Servers_.28Recommended.29)

Comment: @HappyCoder How's everything so far ? Any problem after the upgrade ? I'm planning to do the same thing and I'd like to know your experience.

Comment: It all went well. I got an update yesterday also and everything is perfect for me

Answer (score 1):

1.install update-manager-core

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core
```

2.upgrade

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```