# Moing from 12.04 to 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, updates

I'm currently on a system that runs only 12.04. I have downloaded the 14.04 iso file.
My CD ROM isnt working so i dont have the option of installing through the CD which i followed last time when i installed 12.04.

I tried copying the iso file to a 8GB USB stick and booting from that. But due to some reason the system is not able to boot from the disk.

Even though i have been using Ubuntu for a long time, i don't get along with the terminal very well. I tried reading a couple of simple instructions on updating software through ttyl, but i'm getting some error.

Can someone help me out here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all make startup disk(I mean USB stick here) ,using Startup Disk Creator tool available when you type it on dash board

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/usb-creator-gtk/

After Successful USB Stick Burning go to the boot menu of your BIOS and disable fast booting and then make sure that the USB Stick is been detected by your board ..

If your BIOS detects the Stick just go to boot menu and make it a primary boot option 
that's it you can now install UBUNTU 14.04
OR 
There is one more option out there if you have a good internet connection you can upgrade the distribution to 14.04 see this

[Upgrading 12.04 to 14.04 beta directly (without the intermediate 12.10 release)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/443556/upgrading-12-04-to-14-04-beta)

Answer (score 0):

In the link you can find different way to upgrade to new Ubuntu version from older version.
[How do I upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu)

I hope that helps.